Flutter App Crashes on Android 8 and Below with Error "androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor"
I'm facing an issue with my Flutter app where it crashes on Android 8 (Oreo) and below. The crash report in the Google Play Store shows the following error:
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor
Here’s my styles.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>

The app works fine on Android 9 and above, but it crashes on Android 8 and below.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Same problem ...
